# SSL Working on 8888 but not 443

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-web-services, https

I have Apache set up to server HTTPS traffic.
If all I change in the 000-default.conf is `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:8888>`, I am able to hit the page externally on port 8888. However, on port 443, I get a "Connection Refused" error from the browser.

This is an AWS server but the port is definitely open at that layer. I have no idea why 443 doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you also adding the requisite SSL certificate/key/chain directives to your vhost? What do your apache logs say?

Comment: Yes, added those. I can confirm they work because when using port 8888, the browser confirms that the connection is secure.

Comment: Well, then I'd double and triple-check firewall rules, both on your host as well as your EC2 security groups. Have you verified that the server is actually listening on 443? `$ netstat -tunlp | grep 443`

Comment: The response to that is: tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: Will listening on 0.0.0.0:443 (forcing ipv4 only) help?